# Special Operators Definition in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, operators, definition

How do you define a special operator in Mathematica, for example a special type of additive or multiplicative operator? I did that in the past but I can't recall where I put the code. 
I tried defining this filled small circle operator on two matrices :

```
A_\[FilledSmallCircle] B_ := 
  Which[(MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) && (MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), 
   A.B, ! (MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) && (MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), 
   A@B, (MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) && ! (MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), 
   Transpose[B@Transpose[A]]];
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The left hand side is being interpreted (if you put a space between `A_` and the `\[FilledSmallCircle]`) as `Times[\[FilledSmallCircle], Pattern[A, Blank[]], Pattern[B, Blank[]]]`. You need to create an infix notation. See the various answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you are trying to make an operator with an infix action. If you compare it to the built-in infix operators `+`, `*`, `**`, `\[CircleTimes]`, etc... you'' see that they are all interpreted into their `FullForm`: `Plus`, `Times`, `NonCommutativeMultiply`, `CircleTimes`, respectively.

You should probably try to create something similar. So start with

```
BigDot[A_, B_] := Which[
          (MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) &&  (MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), A.B, 
         !(MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) &&  (MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), A@B, 
          (MatrixQ[A] || VectorQ[A]) && !(MatrixQ[B] || VectorQ[B]), Transpose[B@Transpose[A]],
          True, HoldForm[BigDot[A, B]]];
```

Note that I added the last line as a catch-all for when neither A nor B are a matrix or a vector.

Then create the infix notation part. The hard way would be to make some `MakeExpression` and `MakeBoxes` definitions. The easy way is to use the [NotationPackage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html)

```
Needs["Notation`"]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[FilledSmallCircle]"], BigDot]
```

Comment: seems I submitted an incomplete comment above... a comma before `True` is missing in your code (cut and paste problem probably)

Comment: @acl: So my answer is not better than yours? :(   
Anyway thanks for picking up the typo, it was a cut and paste problem - the default for `BigDot` was an afterthought and added after the rest of the post. Normally I check the code in a fresh notebook before posting...

Comment: actually the comment was "much better than mine, but...", I just didn't paste the "but" part! Anyway, your answer's so much less clunky than mine it's funny.

Answer (score 4):

Try (just cut and paste this):

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"A_", " ", "\[FilledSmallCircle]", " ", 
     "B_"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"Which", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "A_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "A_", "]"}]}], ")"}], "&&", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "B_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "B_", "]"}]}], ")"}]}], ",", 
RowBox[{"A_", " ", ".", "B_"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"!", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "A_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "A_", "]"}]}], ")"}]}], "&&", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "B_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "B_", "]"}]}], ")"}]}], ",", 
RowBox[{"A_", "[", "B_", "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "A_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "A_", "]"}]}], ")"}], "&&", 
RowBox[{"!", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"MatrixQ", "[", "B_", "]"}], "||", 
RowBox[{"VectorQ", "[", "B_", "]"}]}], ")"}]}]}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Transpose", "[", 
RowBox[{"B_", "[", 
RowBox[{"Transpose", "[", "A_", "]"}], "]"}], "]"}]}], "]"}]]]
```

Now I've entered this with the `Notation` palette, so actually it looks like this on screen:
[image]
(the palette inserts various boxes where necessary). It just looks horrible when I cut and paste due to the explicit string representation of everything.

EDIT: That is: type `"Needs["Notation`"]`, causing a palette to appear. Click on the first button, whereupon this

[image]

appears. Inside the first yellow box type `A_ \[FilledSmallCircle] B_`, and in the second,

```
Which[(MatrixQ[A_]||VectorQ[A_])&&(MatrixQ[B_]||VectorQ[B_]),A_ .B_,!(MatrixQ[A_]||VectorQ[A_])&&(MatrixQ[B_]||VectorQ[B_]),A_[B_],(MatrixQ[A_]||VectorQ[A_])&&!(MatrixQ[B_]||VectorQ[B_]),Transpose[B_[Transpose[A_]]]]
```

The result looks like this
[image]

and, when evaluated, defines what you want. Alternatively, after the `Needs` bit, just cut and paste what I gave above.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it gives the error message: Notation::notapatu: Warning: The pattern A_. is being interpreted as a notation and not a pattern. Use an embedded NotationPatternTag TemplateBox wrapper if you want this pattern to be treated as a genuine pattern. >>

Comment: @Phil Sorry for that, try again (cut and paste again the last piece of code); I've added a space between `A_` and `.` that somehow was missing.

Comment: @Phil well, it works here by cut and pasting. Since Simon's answer works, though, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: OK I wonder what's going on i am using mma 8 without the latest update. anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Phil I am using 8.0.1 on (now) OS X 10.7 and (before) 10.6. Should not really make a difference, though.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica has some operators without builtin definitions like CirclePlus and CircleTimes that you can define. I'm iPhoning now so I can't check,  but I assume FilledSmallCircle is just a character and not an operator. It's less trivial to define that as an operator,  but you might want to check the Notation package.

Comment: @sjoerd: I know FilledSmallCircle is just a character and not an operator. I Here I want to provide a definition to that character.Mathematica has some operators without builtin definitions like CirclePlus and CircleTimes that you can define. My question is how to implement a particular def in mathematica

Comment: @Phil maybe http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html

Comment: @Phil: I think that Sjoerd's point was that it won't accept the infix definition without some `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` definitions. The [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) simplifies this for you.

Comment: Wow! We could create a new meme ... IPhoned == Not Checked